# Dynamic width in table column for webkit

Tags: html, css, webkit

I want to create a good looking separator for my web app:

[image]

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/sAUvk/

It works fine with Firefox (v4) but Chrome (v10) just shows the middle column. When I set the width of the left and right column manually it works too, but I want  them to fill the space which is left. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The left and right cells are collapsing. Adding content would obviously give them width, but so does adding padding in the CSS: j[sfiddle.net/sAUvk/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/sAUvk/1/)

**Edit:** Why not just set `colspan=3`?

Comment: thx that solved it. I dont set colspan, because i would not be able to set the left and right gradient

Comment: great! that made it much easier